# Using odd and even CSS selectors

Tags: css

I'm trying to use CSS's odd and even selectors, but I can't wrap my head around what is happening in my code... How is `gmail-message-wrapper` being selected?

The 3 `gmail-message-container`s should be selected and have alternating colors.. What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/0d883fcz/

*HTML*:

```
<body style="width:400px;">
    <div>
        <div id="gmail-message-wrapper">
            <div id="gmail-message-container">
                <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
            </div>
            <div id="gmail-message-container">
                <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
            </div>
            <div id="gmail-message-container">
                <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
                <br>
                <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*CSS*:

```
#gmail-message-wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#gmail-message-wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: you need to select the children and use class , id can be used once per document https://jsfiddle.net/0d883fcz/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ID should be used only *once* in a page. Try to give these DIVs a common class and seperate IDs to select them.

Addition:

Use the even and odd pseudo-selectors on the children (`.gmail-message-container`), not on the container (and make that a class, not an ID):

https://jsfiddle.net/yfjfwp5p/

Comment: This is the answer that correctly pointed out both errors first.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.gmail-message-container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.gmail-message-container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<body style="width:400px;">
  <div>
    <div id="gmail-message-wrapper">
      <div class="gmail-message-container">
        <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
      </div>
      <div class="gmail-message-container">
        <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
      </div>
      <div class="gmail-message-container">
        <span class="trim-text">some.email@some.domain (Some Name)</span>:
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text"><b>Some title</b></span>
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text">Some summary text goes here</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Click the definition of nth-child in w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child)

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: you should turn id into class, like i commented earlier https://jsfiddle.net/0d883fcz/2/ and add some explanation ....

Comment: I can see the difference in the fiddle, not in the code in your answer.

Comment: @Slayther the fiddle is from me, not this answer ;)

Comment: Oh... Excuse me blindness sir

Comment: 1. change id="gmail-message-container" to class="gmail-message-container".    2. change #gmail-message-wrapper:nth-child(odd) to .gmail-message-container:nth-child(odd)

Answer (score 1):

It works because nth-child selects siblings of the element it's applied to; in this case, its applied to the wrapper but should be applied to the container so the children being selected are the message containers.

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows

**CSS:-**

```
#gmail-message-container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#gmail-message-container:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: nop, these should be classes , id can be used only once